# What is wrong with my OFFSET mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have no idea what I did wrong. In my example table below, I am trying to get the `id` which has blue `color` and `number` 4 start from `id` 3. So I use offset, but it echo nothing:

```
SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE color =blue AND number=4 ORDER BY id LIMIT 8 OFFSET 2
```

If I delete `number=4`, then everything is fine:

```
SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE color =blue ORDER BY id LIMIT 8 OFFSET 2
```

How to solve this problem? Thanks

**My table**

```
id | color | number
-------------------
1  | blue  | 4
2  | blue  | 3
3  | blue  | 5
4  | blue  | 4
5  | blue  | 2
6  | blue  | 4
7  | blue  | 3
8  | blue  | 4
```

Comment: `WHERE color =blue` < string. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-literals.html

Comment: *"If I delete number=4, then everything is fine."* - not with `WHERE color =blue` it won't. Again, that's a string. Why don't you edit your question as to what you're *really* using.

Comment: Why don't you post your actual data? Are your table/column names that much of a secret?

Comment: @chris85 which is what I said about 12 mins. prior to *this comment*. So somebody posted an answer and now... well, the hole just gets deeper and deeper. *Hop hop!*

Comment: @Fred-ii- yea, I noticed OP commented on answer but not to comments here, nor updated code, guess help isn't needed. I even have my hole jump in boots on today.

Comment: @chris85 [which this seems to be the case...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34911968/what-is-wrong-with-my-offset-mysql#comment57560103_34912115). Hey, let's post an answer and we might get a solid response? ;-)

Comment: chris85, my data is not secret. Even I want, stackoverflow won't allow me, I just want to make a simple question.

Comment: you guys sort it out. I'll pass on this one.

Comment: @conan Copy and paste your actual query here. There's no way that query would work unless you are running it through some interface; or maybe even show your PHP usage here..

Answer (score 1):

Compare your color column to a string value e.g. 'blue'

```
SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE color ='blue' AND number=4 ORDER BY id LIMIT 8 OFFSET 2
```

EDIT: Also if you you would have two rows or less *total* that would be returned by that where clause you won't get any rows with an offset of 2 since the offset will skip the first two results.  With the data you posted this wouldn't be the case but in case the data you were using was different than what you posted here this might explain what you're seeing.

Comment: OP: *"If I delete number=4, then everything is fine"*.

Comment: I had tried that, didn't work. If I don't use AND number = 4, then it is fine, but  I need to find id also equal to 4.

Comment: @conan had you been reading my comment up there, it would have avoided this answer altogether. Or, are you only responding to answers only?

Comment: @fred-ii Didn't see your earlier comment, typically only look at other answers when posting.

Comment: @JohnKlehm My comment about that wasn't to you, it was to the OP ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Fair enough :)